# SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0: Jest fails running tests all of a sudden

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

All of my tests fails all of a sudden.

The error is quite vague and low-level. I am not sure exactly what should I do and what it means...

I have tried: 
- installed jest globally
- uninstalling jest globally and running it locally (jest 24.8.0)
- changed my node version lower and upper (currently using 10, tried 8, and it was working previously with 10)

Below is the error that I get...

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

      3 |  *
      4 |  * @link http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/#working-with-react-16
    > 5 |  * @copyright 2017 Airbnb, Inc.
        |               ^
      6 |  */
      7 | // const enzyme = require("enzyme");
      8 | // const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

      at Runtime._loadModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:568:59)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/entities/lib/decode_codepoint.js:1:106)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Tokenizer.js:3:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/Parser.js:1:106)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/index.js:1:103)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/parse.js:4:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/lib/cheerio.js:5:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/cheerio/index.js:5:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:15:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/index.js:3:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test-setup.js:5:15)
```

Comment: It means something is trying to interpret javascript file as JSON.

Comment: Hi, can you please put your tsconfig.json.

Comment: @Avi Could you please tell me what parts you're interested in ? compilerOptions? "jsx": "Preserve"

Comment: I was having the same issue and resolved it by upgrading my `babel-jest` package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and spent more than 4 hours debugging this, trying to add babel, configure plugins and many more things... I decided to ask for help from a coworker and after 30mn he did realize that the only thing needed was:

Updating:

```
'^.+\\.js': 'babel-jest',
```

To

```
'^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
```

Note the $ at the end... babel-jest was running on js**on** just like it'd for js...

Comment: Hey! I'm still get the error after put this `"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }`